# Rotation third person in direction to camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, transform, quaternions

I want my object to rotate towards the camera at the same time when I rotate the camera, so that the player while walking is always oriented in the direction of the camera, as in typical third-person games.
Unfortunately, any method used so far leads me to a rotation of the object, slightly behind, the rotation of the camera.
I've been looking for a solution for a week and I'm desperate.
I publish a video of the rotation I have with an object.

[video of the late rotation](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cYhI2kgREN)

```
private Rigidbody rb;
public float speed = 1.0f;

void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    }

direction = Camera.main.transform.forward;
direction.y = 0.00f;

private void FixedUpdate ()
{

 Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rb.transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
rb.MoveRotation(newRotation);
 }  

}
```

Comment: Increasing the `speed` variable should solve your problem, since the delay it's cause by the Quaternion.Lerp call, which smooths the transition between the two rotations. Also, if you need to have the same rotation for Camera and Rigidbody, just place the Rigidbody as a child of the Camera.

Comment: I can increase the speed out of all proportion, the object rotates faster during rotation, but it always arrives late. If I position the object as a child in the camera, what script does it take to solve the problem?

Comment: No script, the rotation in directly inherited from the parent (in this case, the Camera).

Comment: But this way it will always be in front without rotating, like a viewfinder. The effect instead would be that the object rotates at the same time as the rotation of the camera..As in these games for example ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shZ6uPSA7UA )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inappropriate use for `Quaternion.Lerp` because you aren't working with a proportion of how far to move. Currently, you're basically telling it to only rotate a tiny percentage of the way to the target rotation.

You should rather use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html), because you can easily calculate angular rotation based on `deltaTime` (or, `fixedDeltaTime` as you use):

```
public float speed = 30f; // max rotation speed of 30 degrees per second

// ...

Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(rb.transform.rotation, targetRotation, 
        speed * Time.deltaTime);
rb.MoveRotation(newRotation);
```

After re-reading your question, now it seems that you don't want a smooth transition/lerp. In that case, just set the rotation to the target rotation:

```
rb.MoveRotation(targetRotation);
```

If even that is too much interpolation/not immediate enough, you could set the rigidbody's rotation in `Update`:

```
private void Update ()
{
    rb.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
}
```

Comment: Now it turns in a different way, better I think, however the rotation of the camera always ends before that of the object (even if I increase the angular rotation by a lot).
Perhaps simply in those games the "forward" of the object is always facing the direction of the camera in another way

Comment: @DanielePappalardo After re-watching your video, I don't see what's wrong with it unless you simply don't want to interpolate at all... In that case why not just use `rb.MoveRotation(targetRotation);`? I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: What is wrong is that Ethan does not turn in sync with the camera especially if I rotate the camera very quickly the camera is already rotated and Ethan still has just started rotating, while in games they usually rotate both at the same time (like a raycast or a child on the camera that move at identical times).
With rb.MoveRotation (targetRotation) it is faster but if I rotate the camera quickly there is the same problem. I thought to put an invisible cube, son of the camera, in front of the object and use LookAt on him but I don't know if it is a good solution

Comment: @DanielePappalardo Then you don't even want the rigidbody to interpolate between physics updates... Just use `rb.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);` and call it in `Update`.

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't want to use update because I read that the physics update must be done was  fixedupdate but in fact it is more efficient. Do you think I can have problems with physics like this?
Another solution that I have found is to use Quaternion.LerpUnclamped with a high number for t, do you think it will be fine? ... the only thing I have never understood is because if I rotate in fixedupdate the rigidbody is held at a speed about 0.5 even if I walk at a speed of 1/3. In update instead the rigidbody goes from 0.0 to 3 based on my speed.

Comment: The problem is that your camera is moving in `Update`, and you need to tell the physics engine the rotation based on the camera at that moment, you don't want to wait for FixedUpdate. If you want the most accurate rigidbody physics behaviour unity can reasonably provide, you would really want to be using AddTorque. However, turning 90 degrees in an instant is not realistic physical behaviour. I think setting `rb.rotation` in `Update` is the compromise between instant rotation and physics simulation that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of these code I think. You can just place the camera as your character's child transform in the hierarchy, and align it so that it is above and behind your character. When he moves, the camera should follow automatically.

Comment: But if I rely only on the rotation of the child - camera object, when I rotate the camera I will have the object in front, but reported it will not rotate, it will be like a viewfinder. The effect instead would be that the object rotates at the same time as the rotation of the camera